# Cant write to public_html even though im in group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

Im on Ubuntu Desktop.

I created a public_html folder in /home/$user/public_html

I then set up a virtual host for this folder as default.

I then ran the following commands, as laid out in many tutorials.

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/$USER/public_html
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/$USER/public_html
```

But when I goto public_html the folder has a padlock on it and I cant drop files into it. The test php script I created under sudo works fine and so apache can write files, but I thought being added to the group, I should be able to drop files into there and create new files too?

What am i missing?

Comment: This is as the `$USER` user you're testing? Did you log out and in again to apply the group?  Execute `groups` while logged in as that user to verify that the `www-data` membership has been applied.

Comment: Yes thats it Michael, thank you, of all the guides/help I looked at nothing mentioned log out and in again. Thanks!

Comment: Michael if you post as an answer I can award it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user's group memberships are applied at login, meaning that if a the currently logged-in user (which is what populates the `$USER` environment variable) is added to an existing group, that group membership won't become immediately available.

It can be corrected by logging out and back in again. If your system has `newgrp` available, you can also use that tool to apply membership to the group immediately. See `man newgrp` for full usage details.

```
# Apply the new group membership to `$USER` right away:
$ newgrp www-data
```

However, `newgrp` also changes the user's active primary group. You will want to restore that to it's original. If the user had a private group, reestablish that as the active group for this shell:

```
$ newgrp $USER
```